# Trying to create an appointment with Office javascript API

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an Office Outlook add-in and I need to save the current appointment from the add-in task panel.

I am calling the function [saveAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5#saveasyncoptions-callback) from the docs and I get a callback:

```
OSF.DDA.AsyncResult = {
    status: "succeeded",
    value: "AQMkADAwATE4MTcxLWE3MDQtY2Q3MS0wMAItMDAKAEYAAANujGeKJf27QJ3WnbZQfHXkBwAv9Xp3V8mlSaPlDEU8GYpFAAACAQ0AAAAv9Xp3V8mlSaPlDEU8GYpFAAEmXsrOAAAA"
}
```

So, it seems the save was successful.
However, I do not see any appointment created in my calendar or in others.

What's going on there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `setAsync` rather than `saveAsync`.